# Serialize a Dictionary<string, object> that contains a List<string>?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, invalidoperationexception

I've found a Serializeable Dictionary which works quite fine: http://www.jankowskimichal.pl/en/2010/10/serializabledictionary/

But I'm getting an exception whenever one of the objects in the dictionary is simply a list of strings.  .NET is telling me it can't serialize it:

```
Serialize 'C:\bin\Debug\Settings\Default.xml' : System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] may not be used in this context.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterObject.Write1_Object(String n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterObject.Write2_anyType(Object o)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o)
   at ShadowBot.Classes.SerializableDictionary`2.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) in c:\Classes\SerializableDictionary.cs:line 114
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable, String name, String ns, Boolean isNullable, Boolean wrapped)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterShadowSettings.Write2_ShadowSettings(String n, String ns, ShadowSettings o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterShadowSettings.Write3_ShadowSettings(Object o)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o)
   at Classes.XmlSerializer.Serialize(String Path, Object Object) in c:\Classes\XmlSerializer.cs:line 29
```

Is this even possible? I'd like this capability and just assumed you could nest objects like this.  If this isn't possible, is there a way I can just write the dictionary to disk (doesn't have to be XML) and then re-load it without me having to write custom wrappers for this? I was originally a mac developer and this type of serialization was quite simple, so maybe I'm missing something on .NET.

Edit: When trying odyss' example i get:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfstring:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might have better luck with `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer`. Example:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dict.Add("test", new List<string>() { "t", "b" });

StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlString))
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, List<string>>));
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, dict);
}
```

This generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringArrayOfstringty7Ep6D1 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><KeyValueOfstringArrayOfstringty7Ep6D1><Key>test</Key><Value><string>t</string><string>b</string></Value></KeyValueOfstringArrayOfstringty7Ep6D1></ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringArrayOfstringty7Ep6D1>
```

Comment: How did you actually get the string?

Comment: @Geesu do you mean, how do you deserialize it?

Comment: No how did you paste what it generated? I'm trying to just print to console like this: http://pastebin.com/3W7BZEtD   The length is always 0

Comment: `xmlString.ToString()`, do it outside the `using`-clause or call `writer.Flush()` to make sure the writer flushes before reading out the string.

Comment: Yea I was doing it inside, that was the problem.  What's strange is it works fine with your example, but with my dict that contains data I'm getting: another exception (see edit above)

Comment: Yours works b/c you specify the list in the type, I have to specify "object".  This fails:             Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dict.Add("test", new List<string>() { "t", "b" });
            dict.Add("test2", "zomg");

Comment: You need to notify the serializer in compile-time of any custom types that you are using which may popup in an object-valued property or field. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with serializing generic lists.  Try changing the list into an string array `string[]` before serializing and then back to a `List<string>` after deserializing.  This is very easy to do and may solve your problem:

```
//List<string> to string[]
string[] sArray = sList.ToArray();

//string[] to List<string>
List<string> sList = sArray.ToList();
```